# AVPlayer layer doesn't change video size

Tags: swift, avplayer

I'm trying to change video size and I found that I have to use layer.
I try to do this in AVPlayer View Controller.
Here's my code`

```
        let newPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: URL.init(string: videoUrl)!)
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: newPlayer)

        layer.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

        self.player = newPlayer
        self.player?.play()`
```

What i'm doing wrong?
And another question is AVplayer play video with it's maximum size? Or all videos are played with some fixed size?